# Can cnosdb ensure atomicity of batch writes in a distributed environment?

Tags: distributed, cnosdb

For example:
INSERT m0(TIME, f0) VALUES(2079939785551584142, NULL), (1243152233754651379, 12321);
The first line is illegal, the second line is legal.
Can it ensure that either all writes succeed or all fail during writing?

Either all succeed or all fail.